# Convert an integer to an array of digits

Tags: java, integer

I try to convert an integer to an array. For example, 1234 to `int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};`.

I've written a function:

```
public static void convertInt2Array(int guess)  {
    String temp = Integer.toString(guess);
    String temp2;
    int temp3;
    int [] newGuess = new int[temp.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<=temp.length(); i++) {
        if (i!=temp.length()) {
            temp2 = temp.substring(i, i+1);
        } else {
            temp2 = temp.substring(i);
            //System.out.println(i);
        }
        temp3 =  Integer.parseInt(temp2);
        newGuess[i] = temp3;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=newGuess.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(newGuess[i]);
    }
}
```

But an exception is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" 
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) 
>
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504) 
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) 
> at q4.test.convertInt2Array(test.java:28) 
> at q4.test.main(test.java:14) 
> Java Result: 1

How can I fix this?

Comment: Integer.toString(n).chars().map(a->a-'0').toArray();

Comment: Added support for negative values check my answer below ( For new developers since it's been 8 years )

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The immediate problem is due to you using `<= temp.length()` instead of `< temp.length()`. However, you can achieve this a lot more simply. Even if you use the string approach, you can use:

```
String temp = Integer.toString(guess);
int[] newGuess = new int[temp.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
{
    newGuess[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

You need to make the same change to use `< newGuess.length()` when printing out the content too - otherwise for an array of length 4 (which has valid indexes 0, 1, 2, 3) you'll try to use `newGuess[4]`. The vast majority of `for` loops I write use `<` in the condition, rather than `<=`.

Comment: your functions can't store value 0

Comment: @hkinterview: They can store a *single* 0, but not leading zeroes. That's a problem with your design rather than my implementation though. Either you need to specify the length in the method call, or move away from `int` as a representation - because `00001` is the same `int` value as `1`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you explain me why you have put `-'0'` in the line `newGuess[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';`

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya: Because that's the simplest way to get from `'0', '1', '2'` etc to the integer representations of those digits.

Comment: @JonSkeet Pardon me. I still didn't got it, in the above example String `temp` will become ="1234". so when we get `temp.charAt(0)` it is `1` ,`temp.charAt(1)` it is `2`  and so on. but why is that value not assign to the `int array` as `newGuess[0]=1`,`newGuess[1]=2` and so on

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya, no, `temp.charAt(0)` isn't `1`, it's `'1'` - the *character* '1'. That has an integer value of 49, because the Unicode character 49 is the digit 1. It's important to differentiate between the *character* value and the integer value that it represents as a digit.

Comment: `newGuess[i] = Character.getNumericValue(temp.charAt(i))` can also be used in place of `newGuess[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0'`

Comment: What about negative numbers this is an incomplete answer

Comment: @Phil: I'm not sure the question really makes sense for a negative number, and it doesn't look like the OP needed that (and certainly their original code didn't try to handle it).

Answer (score 65):

You don't need to convert `int` to `String`. Just use `% 10` to get the last digit and then divide your int by 10 to get to the next one.

```
int temp = test;
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
do{
    array.add(temp % 10);
    temp /= 10;
} while  (temp > 0);
```

This will leave you with ArrayList containing your digits in reverse order. You can easily revert it if it's required and convert it to int[].

Comment: Or you can do array.add(0, temp %10) to avoid reversing the list.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet's solution won't work for negative integers.

Comment: This is reversed too?

Answer (score 58):

Use:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num = 1234567;
    int[] digits = Integer.toString(num).chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
    for(int d : digits)
        System.out.print(d);
}
```

The main idea is

1. Convert the int to its String value

   ```java
   Integer.toString(num);
   ```
2. Get a stream of int that represents the ASCII value of each char(~digit) composing the String version of our integer

   ```java
   Integer.toString(num).chars();
   ```
3. Convert the ASCII value of each character to its value.
   To get the actual int value of a character, we have to subtract the ASCII code value of the character '0' from the ASCII code of the actual character.
   To get all the digits of our number, this operation has to be applied on each character (corresponding to the digit) composing the string equivalent of our number which is done by applying the map function below to our IntStream.

   ```java
   Integer.toString(num).chars().map(c -> c-'0');
   ```
4. Convert the stream of int to an array of int using toArray()

   ```java
    Integer.toString(num).chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Let's solve that using recursion...

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();

void intToArray(int num){
    if( num != 0){
        int temp = num %10;
        num /= 10;
        intToArray(num);
        al.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Explanation:

Suppose the value of `num` is 12345.

During the first call of the function, `temp` holds the value 5 and a value of `num` = 1234. It is again passed to the function, and now `temp` holds the value 4 and the value of `num` is 123... This function calls itself till the value of `num` is not equal to 0.

Stack trace:

```
 temp - 5 | num - 1234
 temp - 4 | num - 123
 temp - 3 | num - 12
 temp - 2 | num - 1
 temp - 1 | num - 0
```

And then it calls the *add* method of ArrayList and the value of `temp` is added to it, so the value of list is:

```
 ArrayList - 1
 ArrayList - 1,2
 ArrayList - 1,2,3
 ArrayList - 1,2,3,4
 ArrayList - 1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
private int[] createArrayFromNumber(int number) {
    String str = (new Integer(number)).toString();
    char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();
    int[] arr = new int[chArr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i< chArr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(chArr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just do:

`char[] digits = string.toCharArray();`

And then you can evaluate the chars as integers.

For example:

```
char[] digits = "12345".toCharArray();
int digit = Character.getNumericValue(digits[0]);
System.out.println(digit); // Prints 1
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be much simpler to use the [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) method:

```
public static void fn(int guess) {
    String[] sNums = Integer.toString(guess).split("");
    for (String s : nums) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
public int[] convertDigitsToArray(int n) {

    int [] temp = new int[String.valueOf(n).length()]; // Calculate the length of digits
    int i = String.valueOf(n).length()-1 ;  // Initialize the value to the last index

    do {
        temp[i] = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
        i--;
    } while(n>0);

    return temp;
}
```

This will also maintain the order.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, you can do it like:

```
def convert(a: Int, acc: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] =
  if (a > 0) convert(a / 10, a % 10 +: acc) else acc
```

In one line and without reversing the order.

Comment: But the question is tagged with Java(?).

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
int num = 1234; 

String s = Integer.toString(num); 

int[] intArray = new int[s.length()]; 


for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
    intArray[i] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `substring(...)`.  Use `temp.charAt(i)` to get a digit and use the following code to convert `char` to `int`.

```
char c = '7';
int i = c - '0';
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function:

```
  public int[] convertToArray(int number) {
    int i = 0;
    int length = (int) Math.log10(number);
    int divisor = (int) Math.pow(10, length);
    int temp[] = new int[length + 1];

    while (number != 0) {
        temp[i] = number / divisor;
        if (i < length) {
            ++i;
        }
        number = number % divisor;
        if (i != 0) {
            divisor = divisor / 10;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp2 = temp.substring(i);` will always return the empty string "".

Instead, your loop should have the condition `i<temp.length()`. And `temp2` should always be `temp.substring(i, i+1);`.

Similarly when you're printing out `newGuess`, you should loop up to `newGuess.length` but not including. So your condition should be `i<newGuess.length`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<=` in the for statement should be a `<`.

BTW, it is possible to do this much more efficiently without using strings, but instead using `/10` and `%10` of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following method:

> Convert the number to a string → convert the string into an array of characters → convert the array of characters into an array of integers

Here comes my code:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = 123456; // Example 1
        int num2 = 89786775; // Example 2

        String str1 = Integer.toString(num1); // Converts num1 into String
        String str2 = Integer.toString(num2); // Converts num2 into String

        char[] ch1 = str1.toCharArray(); // Gets str1 into an array of char
        char[] ch2 = str2.toCharArray(); // Gets str2 into an array of char

        int[] t1 = new int[ch1.length]; // Defines t1 for bringing ch1 into it
        int[] t2 = new int[ch2.length]; // Defines t2 for bringing ch2 into it

        for(int i=0;i<ch1.length;i++) // Watch the ASCII table
            t1[i]= (int) ch1[i]-48; // ch1[i] is 48 units more than what we want

        for(int i=0;i<ch2.length;i++) // Watch the ASCII table
            t2[i]= (int) ch2[i]-48; // ch2[i] is 48 units more than what we want
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int count = 0;
String newString = n + "";
char [] stringArray = newString.toCharArray();
int [] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];
for (char i : stringArray) {
  int m = Character.getNumericValue(i);
  intArray[count] = m;
  count += 1;
}
return intArray;
```

You'll have to put this into a method.

Comment: When you're answering questions, try to include a full working code sample. In some cases the person asking the question isn't clear on how a possible solution might work, so providing a code example that they may have to troubleshoot before they can apply it can be frustrating and more confusing. In this case, the original question is almost 6 years old, and already has an answer that's been accepted. If you can, try reviewing unanswered questions, and see if there are any there that you could help with.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments to [Vladimir's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-an-integer-to-an-array-of-digits/8033588#8033588), but I think that this is more efficient also when your initial numbers could be also below 10.

This is my proposal:

```
int temp = test;
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
do{
  array.add(temp % 10);
  temp /= 10;
} while  (temp > 1);
```

Remember to reverse the array.

Comment: Why revert? Just do array.add(0, temp % 10)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that takes an integer and return an array of digits.

```
static int[] Int_to_array(int n)
{
    int j = 0;
    int len = Integer.toString(n).length();
    int[] arr = new int[len];
    while(n!=0)
    {
        arr[len-j-1] = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
        j++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First take input from the user as int, convert it into `String`, and make a character array of size of `str.length()`. Now populate a character array with a *for* loop using `charAt()`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = sc.nextInt();
String str = Integer.toString(num);
char [] ch = new char [str.length()];

for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
{
    ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
}

for(char c: ch)
{
    System.out.print(c +" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using String, Integer, ArrayList, Math:

```
// Actual number
int n = 56715380;
            
            // Copy of the number
            int m = n;
            
            // Find no. of digits as length
            int ln = 0;
            while (m > 0) {
                m = m / 10;
                ln++;
            }
            
            // Copy of the length
            int len = ln;
    
            // Reverse the number
            int revNum = 0;
            ln--;
            int base;
            while (n > 0) {
                base = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                    base = base * 10;
                }
                revNum = revNum + base * (n % 10);
                n = n / 10;
                ln--;
            }
    
            // Store the reverse number in the array
            int arr[] = new int[len];
            for (int i = 0; revNum > 0; i++) {
                arr[i] = revNum % 10;
                revNum = revNum / 10;
            }
            
            // Print the array
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will maintain the same order of the digits in the given number in the resultant array and also won't be using any collection APIs.

1. Starting with the basic approach of reversing a number say `1234`. Get the last digit by modular division (`%`) by `10` and then divide the number by `10` to get the last digit. Do this until the number is greater than `0`.
2. So while getting each last digit you can store it in the array, so you need to initialize an array with the same number of digits in the number, you need to use a `String` functionality there. But with the above step, the resulting array will be in the reverse order of the digits in your number.
3. So start adding the number from the last index of the array to the first index.

   ```
   int num = 1234;
   int[] ar = new int[String.valueOf(num).length()];
   int index = ar.length-1;

   while(num > 0) {

       ar[index--] = num % 10;
       num = num/10;
   }

   System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(ar));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Iterative

```java
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
int remainder = 0;
while(n>0){
        remainder = n%10;
        n /=10;
    integerList.add(remainder);
}
int[] numArray = integerList.stream().mapToInt(x->x).toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

I can not add comments to [the decision of Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-an-integer-to-an-array-of-digits/8033588#8033588), but you can immediately make an array deployed in the right direction. Here is my solution:

```
public static int[] splitAnIntegerIntoAnArrayOfNumbers (int a) {
    int temp = a;
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    do{
        array.add(temp % 10);
        temp /= 10;
    } while  (temp > 0);

    int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[array.size()];
    for(int i = 0, j = array.size()-1; i < array.size(); i++,j--) 
        arrayOfNumbers [j] = array.get(i);
    return arrayOfNumbers;
}
```

Important: This solution will not work for negative integers.

Answer (score -1):

I modified [Jon Skeet's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-an-integer-to-an-array-of-digits/8033593#8033593) as it does not accept negative values.

This now accepts and converts the number appropriately:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = -1203;
    boolean isNegative = false;
    String temp = Integer.toString(number);

    if(temp.charAt(0)== '-') {
        isNegative = true;
    }
    int len = temp.length();
    if(isNegative) {
        len = len - 1;
    }
    int[] myArr = new int[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isNegative) {
            myArr[i] = temp.charAt(i + 1) - '0';
        }
        if(!isNegative) {
            myArr[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
    }

    if (isNegative) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            myArr[i] = myArr[i] * (-1);
        }
    }

    for (int k : myArr) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
-1
-2
0
-3
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main(String k[])
{  
    System.out.println ("NUMBER OF VALUES ="+k.length);
    int arrymy[]=new int[k.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
    {
        int newGues = Integer.parseInt(k[i]);
        arrymy[i] = newGues;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question refers to converting an int not a String