# Split Digits into an array

Tags: arrays

I am doing this in Java

I want to split digits of an Integer,

```
int Pin=125;
```

To an array,

```
int Pin_Extracted={Pin[0], Pin[1], Pin[2]};
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
class name {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        int Pin;
        String Names[][] ={ {"Mr.","Mrs.","Miss.","Dr.","Sir","Late","Professor","Gadha","Master","Teacher"},{"Abhigyan","Akashdeep","Anish","Adarsh","Ashutosh","","Anik","Shivam","",""},{"Saha","Mukkherjee","Pandey","Shaw","Bannerjee","Dey","Gupta","Singh","",""} };        
        System.out.println("Enter your 3 digit code name :");
        Pin=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        char cn[]=Pin.toCharArray();
        int cn1=cn[0], cn2= cn[1], cn3= cn[2];
        String Name1=Names[0][cn1], Name2=Names[1][cn2], Name3=Names[2][cn3];
        System.out.println(Name1+" "+Name2+" "+Name3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share whatever you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know you're doing that in Java. But try asking a question and providing some code ;)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/szaoqoe1yif5i0i/drop.txt?dl=0

This is my program, Iwant to have code name for every single name but it says java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 48

Comment: @AbhigyanSingh Editing the post instead of adding a dropbox link would be amazing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert the integer to a string first.

```
String pinStr = Integer.toString(Pin);
```

Then iterate over the new String as an array of characters, assigning them to a new array of ints as you go.

```
int [] pinExtracted = new int[pinStr.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < pinStr.length(); i++){
    pinExtracted[i] = Integer.parseInt(pinStr.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding similar solutions to ones already available to not promote duplication [[reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-integer-to-array-of-digits)]

Comment: I used it but it said " some messages have been simplified,recompile with- Xdiags:verbose to get full output ".

Comment: Normally there should be a more useful error message along with that. Please check for another error message and double check the code (e.g. .length() instead of .length).

Comment: Now it says : char cannot be converted into java.lang.string

Comment: Sorry, use Character.getNumericValue(pinStr.charAt(i)) instead of Integer.parseInt().

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void int [] convertToArray(int pin){
     StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
     sB.append(pin);
     String toConvert = sB.toString();
     int [] splittedValue = new int [toConvert.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < toConvert.length; i++){
        splittedValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(toConver.charAt(i));
    }
 return splittedValues; 
 }
```

I think this works...regards

Comment: There is no good reason to use a `StringBuilder` here. Just saying.

Comment: Nor is there a good reason to use `Integer.parseInt` - `Character.getNumericValue` is easier.