# How to put two numbers separated by a space into two different arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have two number inputs

1010 212

I want to put these into two different arrays ([1 0 1 0] and [2 1 2])

This is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Array[] = new int[8];
        int Array2[] = new int[8];
        int i = 0;
        Scanner getNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
       do {
            Array[i] = getNumber.nextInt(); 
            i++;
       } while(getNumber.hasNextInt());


            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Array));

    }
}
```

But I get this as an output

[1010, 212, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

(I put 8 as a generic array length because the java compiler forced be to initialize each array)

Comment: so you want to read in a number and each number be an Array of all the digits consisting of that number?

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the numbers first then initialize your arrays based on the length of your number. You can get the length by turning it into a string. Once you are left with a number and an empty array, you can [split an integer into an array of its digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-integer-to-array-of-digits) a number of ways.

```
int[] array, array2;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int a, b;

a = in.nextInt();
b = in.nextInt();

array = new int[Integer.toString(a).length()];
array2 = new int[Integer.toString(b).length()];

int i = 0;
while(a > 0) {
    array[i] = a % 10;
    a /= 10;
    i++;
}

i=0;
while(b > 0) {
    array2[i] = b % 10;
    b /= 10;
    i++;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```