# Changing numbers depending on position

Tags: java, loops

Hello I'm currently coding something for class. We are basically making a credit card checker to pull the numbers from a text file. The rules we have to follow for the check digit are the following.

- Drop the last digit from the card number. The last digit is the check
  digit.
- Reverse the digits.
- Multiply the digits in odd positions (1, 3, 5, etc.) by 2.
- Subtract 9 from any result higher than 9.
- Sum all the digits.
- The check digit (the last number of the card) is the amount that you 
  would need  to add to get a multiple of 10 (Modulo 10)

So I pulled the check digit away by setting a new variable and taking the card # /10. It's in a long so no decimals so this gets rid of the last digit. I then stored that digit as my check digit using %10 of the original number. I then used a loop to reverse the digits which can be seen as:

```
                    long lcards = Long.parseLong(cards);                    
                    long lastDigit = lcards % 10;
                    long newCard = lcards / 10;

                    long reverseCard = 0;

                    while (newCard != 0)
                    {
                        reverseCard = reverseCard * 10;
                        reverseCard = reverseCard + (newCard % 10);
                        newCard = newCard / 10;
                    }
```

I'm now stuck on the next step :/. How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: you might want to store the digits as an array of bytes. Might be easier than using bit operations and calculations.

Comment: How exactly do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Next step:

> Multiply the digits in odd positions (1, 3, 5, etc.) by 2.

That requires you to iterate **all** digits in your input number. And there are two ways to do that:

1. More or less the same as your first attempt to get rid of the last digit - you can use modulo/division operations to "access" each digit in your number in a similar way as you did before!
2. Or, instead of working on **one** number, consider turning the whole number into an array of int values for example; like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-integer-to-array-of-digits). Now you can just iterate that array and make the necessary computations.
   And in the end, just "merge" the array back into a single number. You could even do that **upfront**, to get rid of the last digit.

Hope that helps to get you going on the rest of the exercise!

Comment: If I did it the first way though how would I know when to stop as I wouldn't actually know the length of the card number input seeing as mastercards for example can be 16-19 characters in length?

Comment: I dont get your question. The link I gave you shows you how to turn **any** number into a sequence of values; no matter the length. And besides that; assume you do `long newCard = lcards / 10;` just think for a while how you could detect that you ran out of digits. Hint: worst case ... just try it, and print the values; and see what happens!

Comment: Sorry my question was regarding your first option of doing what I did to get rid of the last digit.  I would have to create a new variable for each position though to do it that way, correct? If so how many positions would I know to create if I don't know the length of the long?

Comment: Sorry, but SO doesn't work this way. We are not a free tutor service that guides you through your complete homework. Especially for "homework" kind of questions, we give hints; but not much more than that. So should get out of that ping/pong mode. But yes, you might have between 16 and 19 chars there ;-) ... that is why any reasonable solution becomes much easier when using arrays to represent that; even when you fill that array "manually" by only using a loop with division/modulo computations (instead of a number to string conversion).