# How convert an int into an Array number by number

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have one number, for example "1256", how can I convert it into an Array?

Actually, I use a constructor of class where I stock it.

```
public SecretBlock(int numbersToArray) {
    this.arrayOfNumbers = new int[AMOUNT];
    for (int i = AMOUNT - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.arrayOfNumbers[i] = numbersToArray % 10;
        numbersToArray /= 10;
    }
}
```

Is there any fine/ adequate solution that may use Java 8 Stream?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer to array of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-integer-to-array-of-digits)

Comment: what is `AMOUNT`? also if you have `1256` how is the array suppose to look? [1, 2, 5, 6]?

Comment: You could convert the int to a string, loop over it and conver it back to int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 int[] result = String.valueOf(numbersToArray)
            .chars()
            .map(Character::getNumericValue)
            .toArray();
```

Comment: or `.codePoints()
            .map(Character::getNumericValue)`

Comment: @Aominè Si senior

Comment: Or `.map(i -> i - '0')`

Comment: I think you meant to write ```.mapToInt(...)``` rather than ```.map(...)```

Comment: @ValentinRuano what does `chars` return?

Comment: @Eugene oups! I see,my bad, thanks for the correction, I guess I relied too much in the intuition that would return something like CharStream if that ever existed

Answer (score 6):

Your current solution is probably the most concise, but if you *really* want to use Java8 you can make use of following snippet:

```
int[] array = Arrays.stream(String.valueOf(numbersToArray).split(""))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();
```

Comment: or without a `Pattern` at all... via `Character#getNumericValue`

Answer (score 3):

Using java-8 one can do:

```
Pattern.compile("")
       .splitAsStream(String.valueOf(numbersToArray))
       .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
       .toArray();
```

Comment: Aah the `Pattern`. I always forget about that one. That is a very clean solution :) +1